# Highcharts acting weird in chrome 30.0.1599.69

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, highcharts

After i updated Google Chrome to newest version (30.0.1599.69), Highcharts is acting weird. I am running jQuery version 1.4.2 and Highcharts 2.1.6, it works perfect in all other browsers, and the version before 30.0.1599.69.

In Chrome v.30.0.1599.69:
[image: In Chrome after update]

How it should look like:
[image]

I have tried several versions of jQuery and tried update to newest version of Highcharts, but that didn't work, and there is no errors in console log..

Comment: It would help if you could show us some html/javascript.

Comment: Hi SteveP, I don't think there is something wrong with the code, since it's only in one version of Chrome, there is something wrong. I just found out that the problem is cx attribute (Chart X Axis). The width is wrong, so it has to be something in the rendering of the chart, but the weird thing is it's only in that version of Chrome...

Comment: Please send us a live demo, have you tried to use master branch http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.src.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. There is a problem with offsetWidth in the new version of Google Chrome, see this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290399

I just made a replace all on offsetWidth to clientWidth, it solves the problem right now. clientWidth value contains the width with the padding, but does not include the scrollBar, border, and the margin, so it's maybe not the right solution for you.